# iphone app crashing rarely can any one tell me reason for crash with following Log?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am doing with tab bar application with four tabs,while switching between two view's in a tab i am getting the issue tell me why this is happening and help me to resolve this.
here is the Log  while crashing application.

```
 Mon Jul 16 21:07:55 unknown MyApp[167] <Warning>: NVVC Dealloc 
        Mon Jul 16 21:08:23 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xe271]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:2688 (24132):10 
        Mon Jul 16 21:08:23 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xe271]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed. 
        Mon Jul 16 21:08:23 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xe271]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation 
        fault 
        Mon Jul 16 21:08:23 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'MyApp' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault 
        Mon Jul 16 21:09:04 unknown lockdownd[20] <Error>: (0x403000) handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #7 from Xcode. Killing connection 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x55fb]) Exited: Killed 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0xa13c]) Exited: Killed 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.MyApp.app[0x137]) Exited: Killed 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (com.apple.accessoryd) Exited: Killed 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:41 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'Mail' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:41 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Memory level is not normal (15%). Delaying auto-relaunch of 'Mail' for 30 seconds. Mon Jul 16 22:00:41 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'app' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:42 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'Phone' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed
```

Answer (score 0):

As per looking at your crash logs, you app i.e. "MyApp" is crashed due to segmentation error. It may have different reasons, probable reasons would be any variable getting used but its already released or any property variable declaration and definition conflict etc..

My suggestion is to set NSZombiEnabled for this issue (in your XCode project) and see the crash logs again. With NSZombieEnabled you will get more detailed information in crash logs.

Answer (score 0):

Something is probably wrong with your second view. It would not appear you are running your project with the debugger on and exceptions enabled, which you should do first. If that does not help start adding some NSLogs to your second view so you can see how far it progresses before the crash.